# RowIndex in CellValueChanged event of my DataGridView is -1

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource

I need to change some data before showing into a DataGridView and I'm using CellValueChanged event. The problem is that e.RowIndex is -1 when datagridview is filling with a datasource.

```
Private Sub dgvList_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvList.CellValueChanged

    ' Convert date to Persian if the edited cell has date
        If dgvList.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells.Item(e.ColumnIndex).ValueType.ToString = "" Then
            ' Do something
        End If

End Sub
```

I update values using it's data source. I change DataTable and the DataGridView updates automatically:

```
        Dim MyRow = dstList.Tables("list").NewRow

        MyRow.Item("date_reported") = PersianDateTime.Parse(txtDateReport.Text).ToDateTime
        MyRow.Item("description") = txtDescription.Text
        MyRow.Item("duration") = txtDuration.Text
        MyRow.Item("coworkers") = txtCoworkers.Text
        MyRow.Item("progress") = numProgress.Value
        MyRow.Item("problems") = txtProblems.Text
        MyRow.Item("date_created") = Now.Date

        ' Add this row to the dataset
        dstList.Tables("list").Rows.Add(MyRow)

        ' Apply changes to database
        UpdateList()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal.  I think it's when the column headers are set.  You just have to add an `If` statement to the event handler to filter that out.

```
If e.RowIndex <>  -1 Then
    'It's a valid cell.
End If
```

Comment: I did. But RowIndex is always -1. DataGridView is filled with two rows but inside that "if" never executed

Comment: You say that you did but I don't see the code you posted in your question.  Anyway, if that's really the case then that sounds like a bug as I've never seen that before.  If you create a new project to test that specifically, do you see the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

```
If e.RowIndex > -1 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex > -1 Then
      Debug.Print(dgvList(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).ValueType.ToString)
      Debug.Print(dgvList(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString)
End If
```

Works fine for me.

How are you changing values?
Also post part of the code that changes it. As source of change gives the index not the result (the code you posted).

Comment: I update values using it's data source. I change DataTable and the DataGridView updates automatically